# Qt not installed correctly

Tags: c++, qt, qt-installer

I've installed the following components for `qt` which were selected as default for me by the app. But I don't get the following screen when creating a `qt-project` for `c++` GUI application:
[image: What I expected!]

But get this:

[image: What I get!]

The list of `qt-package` I've installed are:

[image]

When I create a `qt-widgets-application`, `Qt-Creater` stops responding.

Also, for a note: When I start `Qt-Created`, I get a `zlib1.dll` missing error by `gdb.exe`.
Like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure about updating Qt Creator correctly?

Comment: What was your qt version before install component?

Comment: I had no qt installed on my pc before.

Comment: I've uploaded the screen shot of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107481/discussion-between-anish-silwal-and-wilmort).

Comment: @Wilmort - exe on windows is not right? u sure?

Comment: @ddriver I meant something else but you are right, it is not correct sentence..

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded just the Qt Creator what you need to do to get all the list is to download the Qt binary packages.

If you are on windows I would recommend downloading:

> **Qt 5.x.x for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.2 )**

You can find `Qt 5.6.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.2)` over on [download.qt.io](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.6.0.exe.mirrorlist)